# Setting state with UI (labeling tool)

Tags: gui-construction

I think I've finally got an idea for project to test out the neural net capabilities in Mathematica 11, but first I need to label some data. I'm trying to put together a quick little UI, but I got hung-up on how to actually get the labels out. My code looks like (obviously if you want to play along you'll need a directory of pngs though the labels are non-sense):

```
samples = AssociationMap[Function[x, "None"], FileNames["*.png", {folder}]];
labels = {"Cat", "Dog", "Bird", "None"};
SlideView[Table[Grid[{{Import[Keys[samples][[i]]],ListPicker[samples[[i]], labels]}}], {i, 1, Length[samples]}]]
```

UI wise this looks fine (though it seems to load all images at once -- guess I'll fix that later), but whatever you select in the ListPicker doesn't get set. I've mostly tried inserting Dynamic around various expressions but none of that has worked. Bonus for being able to set multiple values (e.g., if down the road I wanted to classify the overall frame like here and annotate a bounding box). Can anyone suggest how I can get this data out (with the goal of eventually following this type of procedure: https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/neural-networks/out-of-core-image-classification.html?product=language )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, managed to figure it out myself. It requires a bit of a stupid trick: as I mentioned before I tried sprinkling Dynamic in various places -- the most obvious being around 'samples[[i]]' but if you put it there the i turns red which means there is some kind of scoping error. You can get around this with a vacuous looking tweak like so:

```
SlideView[
 Table[Grid[{{Import[Keys[samples][[i]]], 
     With[{i = i}, ListPicker[Dynamic[samples[[i]]], labels]]}}], {i, 
   1, Length[samples]}]]
```

The With statement allows you to get the i value to where you need it and this works.